# Synchronous monk mongodb query in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynccallback, monk

I am working with monk mongodb query in my nodejs application, when I execute the query I get the response asynchronously in a callback mechanism. 
I want to wait for the query to execute and use the result.
The code

```
var mycoll = db.get('collection_name');
mycoll.find({"key":123},function(e,docs){
result=docs[0].arr[n]
});
```

Here **arr** is the array of numbers in a document, **n** is changing constantly thus asynchronous way gives wrong answer.
Can someone modify the code and guide me through.

Comment: Async is the right way to go with Node.  Can you better explain what 'n' is and show the code, maybe we can help you do it in a node way.

Comment: The code is inside a for loop lets say `for(n=0;n<7;n++){...}` value of n is changing. 
The result `docs[0]` is `{"key":9, arr:[0,1,2,3,4,5,6}` , the result for `docs[0].arr[n]` should be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 resp but it ends up with 6,6,6,6,6,6 as it is computed asynchronously.

Comment: Move your loop inside the callback then.